# Define optional char / wchar_t pointer parameter in MIDL

Tags: c++, com, vb6, midl, typelib

I have an existing Win32 C++ DLL, which needs to be accessed by a VB6 client. One of the exported functions is defined as follows:

```
__declspec(dllexport) long __stdcall Foo(long nId, LPCWSTR pszwPath = nullptr);
```

Unfortunately, VB6 always converts strings to ANSI when calling DLL functions via a `Declare` statement. In order to bypass this limitation, I have embedded a type library, which features the following signature for the function:

```
[uuid(...)]
library FooLib
{
    [
    helpstring("FooLib"),
    dllname("Foo.dll")
    ]
    module FooMdl
    {
        [entry("Foo")]
        long __stdcall Foo([in] long nId, [in,unique,string,defaultvalue(0)] LPCWSTR pszwPath);
    }
};
```

This won't compile however, as MIDL generates the following error:

```
error MIDL2020 : error generating type library : AddFuncDesc failed : Foo
```

My next attempt involved utilizing the `optional` attribute:

```
long __stdcall Foo([in] long nId, [in,unique,string,optional] LPCWSTR pszwPath);
```

While this type library can be compiled successfully, the VB6 client crashes with an access violation as soon as the optional string value is omitted.

I am aware that I could change the `LPCWSTR` argument to a `BSTR` type, thereby remedying the problem. However, this would also require me to change the signature and implementation of the existing DLL.

Is it therefore possible to define a `char` / `wchar_t` pointer argument as optional or with a `NULL` default value? Or am I simply out of luck here?

Comment: `this would also require me to change the signature and implementation of the existing DLL` Not necessarily. A `BSTR` pointer is valid where `LPCWSTR` is expected (the opposite is not true). Try it - I'm pretty sure the DLL won't notice anything amiss.

Comment: Yes, you are right, changing the argument to a `BSTR` type and leaving the DLL signature untouched seems to work. The function succeeds in receiving a `NULL` pointer when I omit the string argument in the VB6 client. But I'm still curious to know why this approach isn't possible when dealing with an `LPCWSTR` argument, since it's supposed to be automation compatible as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[string] LPCWSTR` is not in fact automation-compatible. What type would you use when packing this into a `VARIANT`?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about the VT_LPWSTR vartype, but upon taking a closer look, I realized that it belongs to the PROPVARIANT structure. But as a side note, why does VB6 support calling a [string] LPCWSTR argument nonetheless if it's not automation compatible?

Comment: I suppose VB6 supports calling functions with such a parameter because its authors implemented this support. Which they probably did because there was demand for it. I guess I don't understand the question. Can you point to a written rule somewhere stating that VB6 must only support automation types?

Comment: VB6 supports calling most, if not all, Windows API functions (with various degrees of hackery), via `Declare Function` statement. Windows API tends not to be designed with COM automation (or VB6) in mind.